# Extract specific query record and assign to variable in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query inside a VBA sub which using some previously defined date variables, produces a recordset with 5 rows of data that follow the below structure:

**ID | Currency | Date | Rate**

1 | EUR | 24/05/2018 | 1.24

2 | EUR | 23/05/2018 | 1.23

3 | EUR | 22/05/2018 | 1.22

4 | EUR | 21/05/2018 | 1.21

5 | EUR | 20/05/2018 | 1.20

```
Query = "SELECT Hist.ID, Hist.Currency, Hist.DateR, Hist.Rate FROM Hist WHERE Hist.Currency= " & CCY & " AND Hist.DateR= #" & TD & "#" OR " Hist.Currency= " & CCY & " AND Hist.DateRef= #" & Date_1 & "#" OR " Hist.Currency= " & CCY & " AND Hist.DateR= #" & Date_2 & "#" OR " Hist.Currency= " & CCY & " AND Hist.DateR= #" & Date_3 & "#" OR " Hist.Currency= " & CCY & " AND Hist.DateR= #" & Date_4 & "#"
```

I need to assign the Rate for each Date to a separate variable; XRate, Date1Rate, Date2Rate, Date3Rate, Date4Rate. Previously to assign a variable to a record in the query I done the following:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Query)
    XRate = rs("Rate")
```

However this would only work if I split the query into 5 separate queries, one for each date and assign as above. I'm wondering whether there is a smarter way to do this, with the result being 5 Variables each containing the rate for a specific date.

Any help or guidance is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to go about it a slightly different way that works really well, here's my solution:

In the sub routine I assign each variable to a function that takes two arguments, Currency and Date, and returns the Rate for that Date and Currency.

```
XRate = GetRate(CCY, TD)
Date1Rate= GetRate(CCY, Date_1)
Date2Rate = GetRate(CCY, Date_2)
Date3Rate= GetRate(CCY, Date_3)
Date4Rate= GetRate(CCY, Date_4)
```

The above function is stored in a separate module and looks like this:

```
Function GetRate(CCY As Variant, RateD As Variant) As Variant

    Dim Query, rs, Rate
    Query = "SELECT Hist.ID, Hist.Currency, Hist.DateR, Hist.Rate FROM Hist WHERE Hist.Currency= " & CCY & " AND Hist.DateR= #" & RateD & "#"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Query)
    Rate = rs("Rate")
GetRate = Rate
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Hope that helps someone, however if there is a way to access specific records based on specific IDs, i'd really like to know or if there is a more efficient way of doing this operation.